# Aframe audio assets - properly disconnect audio src

Tags: audio, aframe

For some context, I have a series of panorama images and each image has a different audio file (mp3) associated with it. I'm trying to play the relevant audio src when the panorama image changes, however I can't seem to disconnect the previous audio src.

```
    <a-assets>
      <audio
        id="vr-audio"
        src={`http://res.cloudinary.com/concept3d/video/upload/audio_files/${trackId}`}
        preload="auto"
      />
    </a-assets>
      {Boolean(tracks.length) && <a-entity sound="src: #vr-audio" />}
```

The interpolated trackId is changed when the panorama changes and pulled from my components state. I can see the audio src url is changing as expected but when I query for the sound entity the sound src does not update to the new url.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the audio element in place, the component won't catch that. Change the sound component's `src` property instead. It can take a URL. `<a-assets>` isn't really needed unless for preloading.

```
soundEl.setAttribute('sound', 'src', 'http://res.cloudinary.com/concept3d/video/upload/audio_files/${trackId}');
```

If you want to control the audio element, then create a new audio element and assign the new ID.